# Is there a function to encode an array/map using json?

Tags: json, dictionary, go, encode

Is there a function in golang to encode an array/map using json? Something similar to PHP's [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function is what I'm looking for.

Comment: I highly recommend going through https://godoc.org/-/go and https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can encode data structures to json in golang using the **encoding/json** package like this

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    group := map[string]interface{} {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "age": 112,
    }
    b, err := json.Marshal(group) // this converts the structure into json
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error:", err)
    }
    os.Stdout.Write(b)
}
```

[golang json package](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/)